# I just ran my Android app on a BlackBerry 10 simulator. How do I get the .bar file?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I installed Eclipse BlackBerry plugin.
Installed BlackBerry 10 Simulator.
Used CSK file to configure the plug-in.
Ran the Android app on a BlackBerry 10 simulator. How do I get the .bar file?

Comment: I think right click on project -> Blackberry -> sign. Or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with the Eclipse BlackBerry plugin, so I don't know if there is a generated bar laying around after running you could use.

But I do know you can go to http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/ and download the Command-line tools. Then you can use the `Blackberry APK Packager.exe` to convert the apk to bar.

Comment: In the bin folder there is only APK. The console even says "Uploading myapp.apk to device". I will try the tools